How to deduct original balance when editing a transaction?
I am creating a web app using .Net8 Blazor Server Side that can create a transaction and every transaction should deduct the balance.
What happened is that when I Add a Transaction:
private async void Submit()
{
    isVisible = true;
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Transaction!.UserID = selectedUser?.id;
    Transaction!.DOCUMENT_NUM = DocumentNumber;
    Transaction.CREATED_DATE = DateValue;
    Transaction.PARTICULARS = Particulars;
    Transaction.AMOUNT = Amount;

    if (Amount > selectedUser!.Balance)
    {
        Snackbar.Add("User does not have enough balance.", Severity.Error);
        return;
    }
    Balance!.UserID = selectedUser?.id;
    Balance.Balance -= Amount;
    var tran = await tranService.AddTransactionAsync(Transaction);
    var bal = await balanceService.UpdateBalance(Balance);
    Snackbar.Add("Transaction added successfully", Severity.Success);
    await vwUserService.GetAllUsers();
    Transaction = new();
    selectedUser = new();
    await GenerateDocumentNumberAsync();
    Amount = 0;
    Particulars = string.Empty;
    users = new();
    users = await vwUserService.GetAllUsers();
    Balance = new();
    isVisible = false;
    StateHasChanged();
    return;
    
}

this will deduct the balance.
But in my Edit Transaction:
async Task UpdateTransaction()
{
    Transaction.ID = VwTransaction.ID;
    Transaction.CREATED_DATE = (DateTime)VwTransaction.CREATED_DATE;
    Transaction.DOCUMENT_NUM = VwTransaction.DOCUMENT_NUM;
    Transaction.UserID = VwTransaction.USERID;
    Transaction.PARTICULARS = VwTransaction.PARTICULARS;
    Transaction.AMOUNT = VwTransaction.AMOUNT;

    var updated = await tranService.UpdateTransaction(Transaction);
    if(updated is not null)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Balance!.UserID = VwTransaction?.USERID;
        Balance.Balance -= Transaction.AMOUNT;
        await balanceService.UpdateBalance(Balance);
        Snackbar.Add("Transaction updated successfully", Severity.Success);
        return;
    }
    Snackbar.Add("Error Encountered", Severity.Error);
}

What I want to do is this:

Let's say I have a balance of 5,000.00.
I added a transaction of 1,000.00.
So the balance should be 4,000.00, since 5,000.00 - 1,000.00 is 4,000.00.
But then I made a mistake in adding the transaction.
Instead of 1,000.00 the correct amount in adding the transaction should be 1,200.00.
So i try to edit the transaction and changed 1,000.00 to 1,200.00.
After editing the transaction, it should be 5,000.00 - 1,200.00 = 3,800.00

I am having trouble adding the 200.00 to the 1,000.00 and deducting the original balance and likewise, if I want to edit the added amount to something that is lower than 1,000.00 and deduct it to the original balance.
But with the code I have shown, it deducts twice. (1) when I add a transaction. (2) When I edit the transaction. The problem is in my Edit Transaction and I don't know how to do it.

It would be easier to keep a list of the transactions and calculate the balance every time you need it. That way if you edit a transaction, the balance follows through all the time. I suspect your problem is Balance.Balance -= Transaction.AMOUNT; - when you edit 1000 to be 1200 you shouldn't then subtract the whole 1200 again. What you should do is subtract the difference between the new amount and the original amount, so "balance = balance - (newamount - old amount)". If newamount is 700 and old amount was 1000 this will cause "balance-(-300)", which will correctly ADD 300 etc

Added 2 variables, 1 for the original amount and 1 for the new amount:
var originalTransaction = await tranService.GetByIdAsync(VwTransaction.ID);
if(originalTransaction is null)
{
    Snackbar.Add("No Transaction Found", Severity.Error);
}

decimal originalAmount = originalTransaction.AMOUNT;
decimal newAmount = VwTransaction.AMOUNT;

and added this in my method to properly deduct the balance:
var updated = await tranService.UpdateTransaction(Transaction);
if(updated is not null)
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Balance!.UserID = VwTransaction?.USERID;
    Balance.Balance += originalAmount;
    Balance.Balance -= newAmount;
    await balanceService.UpdateBalance(Balance);
    MudDialog!.Close();
    Snackbar.Add("Transaction updated successfully", Severity.Success);
    return;
}

this made the deduction process accurate.
